# TypeError: bad operant type for unary -: 'type' ; while extracting keywords form text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, lambda, beautifulsoup

Hi I am writing a code to get tags from a text article using python. I work great but when i try to sort these words python give me 'TypeError'. I looked around this error but can't figure out what to do 
Here is my code:

above problem is solved now but right now i want to get most used word from this text Article and in outer if statement i apply a check that if word are exist in commen.txt file thy should not include in word_dic. but when i run this code it gave me those word also which are already exist in common.txt file
NOTE: Common.txt contain most use words of English. e.g (a,in,of , the) which i don't want to include in word_dic

```
#Loading Libraries
import urllib
import os
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
id= 1
url='http://scitechdaily.com/new-technique-reveals-internal-characteristics-of-photonic-crystals/'
def getKeywords(articletext):
    common = open('C:\\Users\\Hassan Raza\\Desktop\\Mozilla tech article\\common.txt').read().split('\n')
    word_dict = {articletext:float}
    word_list = articletext.lower().split()
    for word in word_list:
        if word not in common:
            if word not in word_dict:
                word_dict[word] = 1
            if word in word_dict:
                word_dict[word] +=1

    sorteddata = Counter(word_dict).most_common()
    #print(sorted(word_dict.items(),key=lambda kv: (-kv[1], kv[0]),reverse=True))


def GetArticles(url,id):
    file = open('C:\\Users\\Hassan Raza\\Desktop\\Mozilla tech article\\Article'+'.txt', 'w')
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

    title= soup.find_all('h1', {'class','title'})
    for titles in title:
        print(titles.text)
    text = soup.find_all('div' , {'class', 'entry'})
    for pg in text:
        articletext=(pg.text.encode('utf8'))
        getKeywords(articletext)

    file.close()

GetArticles(url,id)
```

here is what i am getting in terms of error:

> Line 18 in  print(sorted(word_dict.items(),key=lambda kv:
>   (-kv[1], kv[0]),reverse=True)) TypeError: bad operant type for unary
>   -: 'type'

Help me to solve this problem :)

Comment: Please don't post links to screenshots. Copy and paste the error here as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify types when initializing a dictionary in Python. When you try to do that here:

```
word_dict = {articletext:float}
```

You are actually creating that dictionary with a key-value pair already in it. The key is the original `articletext` and the value is the `float` data type. Just create an empty dictionary:

```
word_dict = {}
```

Comment: ^this will solve your problem. Also I'd recommend you to check `Counter` class which is designed for task like yours. https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter . `defaultdict` is also quite handy, check that one too

Comment: Thank you @TigerhawkT3 it work for me like its perfect